# Is continuous exposure to blue light lethal for mosquito larvae?

Tags: entomology, mosquitoes

I have been observing developing mosquito larvae since 2 days and I saw, while exposing my laser light of blue colour to it, that it becomes unstable on exposure to blue light.
Thus, I wish to ask, will it die or whether it is fine? It has been one day since I shone the light on it, so please tell me: will it grow further or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of relevant results from Google Search for "blue light mosquito larvae". Here is just one of them:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-022-14096-y

They are not all only mosquito related either, such as this one for insects in general:
https://www.nature.com/articles/srep07383

Or you could just find out for yourself. You are already set up for it. All you need is a control group, and preferably a third group that is exposed to high intensity laser light of a significantly different wavelength such as red or green in order to determine if it is just the intensity of the light or the wavelength.